# Error on checkout in Ebizmats Sage Suite Pro(Europe)

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I configure Sage pay extension with mage-world one-step checkout.

There are three payment methods we use on site:

1. PayPal using Sage-pay
2. Sage-pay server
3. Sage-pay Credit Card

During checkout by PayPal I got an error:

> Payment has failed, please reload checkout page and try again. Your card has not been charged.

After searching a lot I found link :

[Payment has failed, please reload checkout page and try again. Your card has not been charged](https://baljitdhanoa.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/payment-has-failed-please-reload-checkout-page-and-try-again-your-card-has-not-been-charged/comment-page-1/)

It works but after make changes in Sales.php, unable to checkout with "Sage Pay Suite [Frontend - DIRECT Integration](Sage-pay Credit Card)"

If disable onestepcheckout all payment methods working fine but I can't use default checkout.

Comment: If you the pro edition you get great support - but ebizmarts only support the onestepcheckout extension (and partially the iwd one). So not the Mage World version. I've used both - my advice would be to ditch thst MageWorld checkout and just stump up for the real thing.

Comment: i use support but not get any reply yet. from last 2 weeks. my client purchased mage world extension so i can't do anything rather than use it

Answer (score 1):

The error 'Payment has failed, please reload checkout page and try again. Your card has not been charged.' in the Ebizmart extension is normally caused by a javascript conflict.  To confirm this, revert your store to the default theme and see if the problem goes away.

If it does, re-enable your theme and start disabling the theme specific javascript files until you find the one that is causing the problem.  To identify them, make sure you have cache disabled and disable merging of javascript if that is enabled.  Load the site and view source to see what theme js is loading.  To remove the js, open this file;

```
app/design/frontend/XXX/YYY/layout/checkout.xml
```

Where xxx yyy are the theme directory.  In this file find this block;

```
<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout</label>
```

Immediately under that, add this with the path of your js to remove - given you 2 methods to help here;

```
<reference name="head">
<!-- remove a file loaded from root/js -->
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>folder/some.js</name></action>
<!-- remove a file loaded from your skin dir -->
<action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>folder/someskkin.js</name></action>
</reference>
```

This will unload the offending js from the checkout process only, which will mean it still loads where needed elsewhere.

Good luck